# picturefill element inside a polymer web component loses container dimensions

Tags: polymer, web-component, picturefill

I'm trying to use the `<picture>` element, which is created by the [picturefill js library](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill), inside of a web component I'm creating using Polymer, but it is choosing the smallest possible image as `<picture>` is not getting any dimensions from the container element.

I have tried giving :host a display:block among a myriad of other atempts at doing this with styling, including making sure the container is 100%, but nothing works.

Here is a [codepen of what I'm trying to do](http://codepen.io/scottnath/pen/RNoBXd) showing the polymer-made element using the smallest image, then the `<picture>` element on it's own showing the correct image.

Note that in the live codepen version that the `<hr>` (horizontal rule) elements created by the polymer-element are the full width and thus understand the correct width of the container.

This is the code in the codepen:

```

```
<polymer-element name="picture-container" attributes="value">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
      display: block;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        padding: 1em;
      }
    </style>

    <hr>
      <h2>Picture In Polymer Element</h2>
      <picture>
        <source srcset="http://www.placecage.com/c/500/500" media="(min-width: 500px)">
        <source srcset="http://www.placecage.com/c/200/200" media="(min-width: 400px)">
        <img srcset="http://www.placecage.com/c/100/100" alt="An example of the picture element">
      </picture>
    <hr>

  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('picture-container');
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<picture-container></picture-container>

<hr>
  <h2>Picture In Polymer Element</h2>
  <picture>
    <source srcset="http://www.placecage.com/c/500/500" media="(min-width: 500px)">
    <source srcset="http://www.placecage.com/c/200/200" media="(min-width: 400px)">
    <img srcset="http://www.placecage.com/c/100/100" alt="An example of the picture element">
  </picture>
<hr>
```

```

any help on this greatly appreciated.

thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE

There is a [running thread on this on the picturefill github issues section](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill/issues/412#issuecomment-68757424). That thread gave a new option in the script section which made this work correctly in Firefox and Safari:

```
<script>
    Polymer('picture-container',{
      ready: function() {
        picturefill({elements: this.shadowRoot.getElementsByTagName('img')});
      }
    });
</script>
```

Example codepen: http://codepen.io/scottnath/pen/Wboayg

I discovered that in Firefox (33.03) if I go into `about:config` and change these two settings to true:

`dom.image.srcset.enabled
dom.image.picture.enabled`

then this mimics the incorrect behavior of chrome for the picture element.

Still no solution though...

Comment: This is a browser bug and you can't do anything about it. In case of Chrome this was fixed and will be released with Chrome 41 (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=446876) and in case of FF you can file an issue. I already said this in the pf issue tracker to you.